# Создание bottomnavigation c другим оформлением

Tags: java, android, bottom-navigation-view

Нужно сделать подобный bottomnavigation. Это невозможно сделать с помощью селектора. Причем он должен быть с радиусом.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так  же пытался сделать через app:itembackground. Это я думаю подходящий вариант, в него можно поставить фон с selector. Но размер не тот
[image: На фото белым выделен фон обеих элементов item.]

Код самого bottomnavigation

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/bottomnavigation_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
```

Код bottomnavigation_bg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <corners android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
                      android:topRightRadius="25dp"/>
   <solid android:color="#4F4F4F"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: В том и дело что вариантов нет. Написал только фон для него: <shape>
         <corners android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
                      android:topRightRadius="25dp"/>
         <solid android:color="#4F4F4F"/>
      </shape>

Comment: Я пробовал изменить фон через app:itembackground. Это сделать можно даже через menu.xml. Но проблема в том что размер фона кнопки не соответствует тому что мне нужно

Comment: Сейчас скину код самого bottomnavigation

Comment: Я знаю, выделил для наглядности. Туда же можно подставить любой фон в формате .xml.

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста еще этот файл - bottomnavigation_bg drawable который

Comment: Простите, ошибся. app:itemBackground нельзя написать в menu.xml. Но можно сделать в selector свойство state_checked. Сейчас поправлю вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По логике я думаю должно быть так - вы сетите background для контейнера bottomNavigationView и отдельно для элементов меню. У меня была подобная задача, ниже прикладываю свой код и попутно объясню как оно выглядит. Вот мой bottomNavigation:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_t"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_nav_menu" />
```

вот файл `selected_text.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#4D4D4D" />
</selector>
```

и поведение такое как вам нужно, цвета конечно у меня свои, но я думаю логика будет понятна. Вам, если этот код у вас приживется, нужно будет добавить только фон для контейнера менюшки. Сделать фоновый drawable файл с закругленными углами я думаю не оч сложно. В фон нужно будет добавить радиус для каждого угла:

```
<corners 
  android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="2dp" android:topRightRadius="0.1dp" />
```

ну и фон то понятное дело тоже нужен будет) Вот есть [видео-урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxIi96ni8GM) как сделать фон, [вот документация](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation) material design

### UPDATE

Решил добить ваш вопрос, вот итоговый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой общий фон виджета:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#1bc0a7" />
    <corners android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

а селекторы которые выше. Надеюсь у вас получится что-то типа такого тоже :)

Comment: Спасибо, хотелось бы еще добавить. Сейчас мне нужно было изменить высоту и ширину данного item. Чтобы фон вписывался в остальную навигацию. Я переопределил в dimen.xml     
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">83dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width" tools:override="true">220dp</dimen>

Comment: про dimen можно тут посмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128178/how-to-use-dimens-xml-in-android, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него

Comment: У меня всё получилось, спасибо